# Is the JVM, a form of VM?

Tags: java, jvm

I am a mainly .NET developer and I do a lot of infrastructure work with techs like ESX and Hyper-V. I find it very odd that the JVM has VM in it (I keep thinking of VMs in the form that sits on an ESX server).

Am I correct in saying that the JVM is an actual VM sitting in a certain ring between the OS and apps (not between hardware and OS)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a virtual machine in the same way that the CLR (part of .NET) is a virtual machine. It's not quite the same as a Hyper-V type VM though... Hyper-V virtualizes common hardware to run an entire operating system so that most code "thinks" it's really running directly on a normal computer.

The JVM or CLR are slightly different in that:

- The instruction set being virtualised has been designed specifically *to* be virtualised. While there is some "native Java bytecode" hardware, that's far from the normal way of running Java. Normally bytecode and IL are JIT-compiled - and the garbage collector is part of the virutal machine, which certainly isn't the case in Hyper-V etc.
- The VM doesn't run an operating system itself - it runs *on* an operating system which it knows about directly, and uses for file system access etc

Both kinds of "virtual machine" are running code in a virtual environment, but the primary concerns of the two are very different.

Comment: Your first paragraph reminds me of something I read a few days ago in how a hypervisor tricks an OS to think that most code is run directly (to prevent OS modifications). Good answer. I actually meant the JVM runs on an OS, when I said "an actual VM sitting in a certain ring between the OS and apps". That can be how it knows about it directly I guess...

Comment: @dotnetdev: Right, yes. And some "computer" VMs run on an OS as well, while some run on the bare metal.

Comment: This concept could be tricky to grasp. I'm glad I have some infrastructure knowledge because I understand everything in this thread.

Answer (score 3):

The Java (and .NET, and Python, and Parrot...) virtual machine is a "simulated computer."  It has instructions and behaviors which are identical across the operating systems the VM runs on, which makes the "cross-platform" aspect work.  The VM itself is platform-specific, of course, to iron out the details for the client code.

So yes, everything back to the Infocom Z-Machine and Knuth's MIX virtual machine are, in fact, "virtual machines."

Answer (score 1):

Wrong [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine#Process_virtual_machines).

Answer (score 1):

While ESX and Hyper-V emulate a computer system,a  JVM only provides execution (and optimization) of java byte code on a supported platform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the JVM takes Bytecode and executes it, and it is able to enforce security restrictions on the application.